# How to set children not overflow parent?

Tags: html, css, angular

An eternal problem.

With my ability, I think that if we want to use scroll view, we have to know exactly the scroll view's height.

In **React Native** is easier because we only need to set `flex = 1` in parent view. And the child view will always inside the parent.

But in web, I dont know how to set it automatic.

As my [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zuxrha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), if I dont set class2's css with `height: calc(100% - 100px)`, how to make it just scroll in the area **which's height =** `window.innerHeight ( == 10vh ) - other element's height`.

My English is not good but hope that everyone can understand my main idea.

Comment: Hi! please check this link if its helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72362199/how-to-prevent-child-div-overflow-out-of-parent-div-on-changing-css-zoom-propert/72362323#72362323

Comment: @JaswinderKaur I checked but I think its not the answer I need. because It's not working with my simple demo. as the link you give me, I add it into `class2` and delete `height`. But the container is sroll, class2 is not. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment `height` on `.class2` and add `display: grid` to `.container`

You can get the same behaviour with `flex` too.

```
    .container {
      height: 90vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .class1 {
      background-color: aqua;
      height: 50px;
    }

    .class2 {
      background-color: aquamarine;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 1rem;
      &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
      }
      &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background-color: whitesmoke;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
      &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    }

    .class3 {
      background-color: violet;
      height: 50px;
    }
```

Comment: hmmmm. I dont know why but I have checked in my code because as I know flex 1 in RN is flex box in web, but it didn't work. So I miss it when I test on demo. and now I get your way to test and is working.

Comment: but it's still not working in my main code. I will find my problem.
have any other solution, @tony? tks you.

Comment: modified answer, if you want to use `flex`

Comment: `.class2` will take `100% - container's other elements' heights combined`. It will not be fixed but dynamic, so it should not cause any problems for you. If this does not work, it means your main code container is inheriting styles from somewhere

Comment: yes -_- I am trying to fix the height of ng-zorro table/devextreme table.